# JAXB bindings generic converter

Tags: binding, xml-parsing, jaxb

In JAXB binding i can change type of element from int to string and so on.

But i want not only data type conversion. I want replace integer Id's with they string equivalent.

This means that for every field i need write method.

Is anyway to get field name from parse method?

```
<!-- Resolve ID's -->
<jaxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Classification']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='id']">
    <jaxb:property>
        <jaxb:baseType>
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" parseMethod="com.company.lookup.Resolver.resolve" />
        </jaxb:baseType>
    </jaxb:property>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining the `javaType` on a per property basis you can override the Java type for an XML schema type in the global bindings section of the external binding document.

```xml
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

   <jxb:bindings>
       <jxb:globalBindings>
           <jxb:javaType name="String" xmlType="xs:int"/>
       </jxb:globalBindings>
   </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```